# Getting error while installing pyseer package using pip or pip3

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, bioinformatics

I am trying to install the pyseer package with pip/pip3 as per the pyseer documentation. However, I get an Error saying :

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyseer (fron versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyseer.

Usually pip and pip3 installation has worked well on my system, I am unable to figure out the issue here.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Which is your Python version? Please provide more details.

Comment: @DiegoRamirez Python version is 3.9.4

Answer (score 2):

Do you have your python installed via anaconda? I know it's kind of a pain to re-install but I finally just caved in and did last night and it really is the best way to go for installing Python packages. I just used it to try and install `pyseer` and it took some time (~5 minutes+), but it worked very well and installed a bunch of useful dependencies which I would have needed to install at some points inevitably anyways:

[image: install pyseer via conda]

Make sure you have `bioconda` added to your conda config (`conda config --add channels bioconda`), too (same for `conda-forge`); but I think these will be by default. Running the `conda config` command given above in parentheses will at least move `bioconda` to the top of conda's list of repos it scans which might speed up download of packages if you're mainly installing bioinformatics stuff, nonetheless.

[image: showing version of pyseer via bioconda]

Of course only 3.8 is the latest Python available through anaconda. You can still have Py 10 installed though, I do, for when I want to use any of the new stuff added since 3.8. (I just have to type `python3.10`)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `pyseer` on neither [PyPI](https://pypi.org) (where pip looks for packages by default) or [TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org) (an instance of PyPI for testing). The [PySeer README](https://github.com/mgalardini/pyseer#readme) suggests two ways to install the package.

One of them is Conda:

```
conda install pyseer
```

However, you will have to install Conda, which can be a bit hard.

---

And the other one is pip. To use pip, you have to *download* (manually) [from here](https://github.com/mgalardini/pyseer/releases) (or clone with Git), then go to that directory on your terminal and run:

```
pip3 install .
```

(Even when the docs recommend `pip`, `pip3` should not have problems to install this).

Answer (score 0):

So I figured what the issue was. Apparently, PIP3 or PIP won't work for Pyseer as it throws conflicting dependency errors, in Windows. Using Conda in a Linux environment does the trick (https://github.com/mgalardini/pyseer/issues/182) .